# Getting the id of the element when click on that element in the list box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a dropdown when I click on the item in dropdown my list box gets populated with set of items realted to that item selected from dropdown..now when I choose one item from list box I want to fetch its ID..My all data is coming form json..pLEASE HELP!!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "DATA.JSON",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(obj) {
            console.log("obj--", obj)
            var jsObject = obj;
            var usedNames = [];
            $('<option>', {
                text: 'Select your Option',
                value: '',
                selected: 'selected',
                disabled: 'disabled',
                location: 'fixed'
            }).appendTo('#dropdown1')
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                if (usedNames.indexOf(value.name) == -1) {
                    $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
                    usedNames.push(value.name);
                }
            });
            $('#dropdown1').change(function() {
                $('#listbox').toggle(this.value != "");
            });

            $('#dropdown1').change(function() {

                $('#listbox').empty();

                $('<option>', {
                    text: 'Select your List Option',
                    value: '',
                    selected: 'selected',
                    disabled: 'disabled'
                }).appendTo('#listbox');

                var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
                console.log("as".selection);
                $.each(jsObject, function(index, value) {
                    if (value['name'] == selection) {
                        var optionHtml = '';
                        for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                            var attr = 'attr' + ('000' + i).substr(-3);
                            optionHtml += '<option value="' + attr + '">' + value[attr] + '</option>';

                        }
                        $("#listbox").css("width", "500px")

                        $("#listbox").css("height", "300px")
                        $('#listbox').append(optionHtml);
                        return false;
                    }
                    var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
                    console.log(selectedOption);
                });
            });
            $("#listbox").on("click", function() {

                console.log("asd", $('#listbox').attr('data-val'));
                $( "#listbox" ).delegate( "td", "click", function() {
                    $( this ).toggleClass( "chosen" );
                });

            })
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line of code

`optionHtml += '<option value="' + attr + '">' + value[attr] + '</option>';`

To

`optionHtml += '<option value="' + attr + '" id="'+ attr+'">' + value[attr] + '</option>';`

Change this code block

```
$("#listbox").on("click", function() {
  console.log("asd", $('#listbox').attr('data-val'));
  $( "#listbox" ).delegate( "td", "click", function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "chosen" );
  });    
});
```

TO

```
 $( "#listbox" ).on( "click", "option", function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "chosen" );
    alert($(this).attr('id')); // this is just for demo to get the id of the clicked option.
 });
```

Points to note.

1) your `#listbox` does not have a td element at all. All it has is `<option>` tags. So change the script to trigger the click event on this option.

2) You are binding the click event to your `td` (which mut be `option`) on every click of the `#listbox` which will cause you binding multiple events and that will cause failure.

3) use the `.on()` selector over `.delegate`. `.delegate()` is deprecated and as of now it doesnt work in most of the mobile browsers.

Comment: No it does not work ..before when i was clciking on an item in list atleast i was getting --asd undefined--but now not even that....

Comment: @Jasmin you will not get it now because I have removed the console.log line from there...

Comment: @Jasmin just click on any of the `option` in list box and then inspect its class. you will see the `chosen` class applied to it.. also to log the value od data attribute you must use `console.log($('#listbox').data('val'));`

Comment: I clicked on the inspect element then there its showing the attribute from where it is coming ..the class is chosen..then what to do next

Comment: your intention is to add a class `chosen` to your `options` inside the `#listbox` element right? The code I provided does that. is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I want to get the ID of the items that I choose from list box...this is my intention

Comment: @Jasmin But there is no id set into these `options` in your code. The code is `optionHtml += '<option value="' + attr + '">' + value[attr] + '</option>';` do you want to set the `key` as the id too?? and then retrieve it..  or the values is also fine for you?

Comment: I want to get the id and retrive it as i want those id's to fetch some other values

Comment: @Jasmin I update my answer. Have a look. Sorry I forgot to intimate you.

Comment: Ah ok i wiil check now!! THANKS

Comment: but why it is saying -undefined- every item that I click it says undefined

Comment: @Jasmin did you change the first line of code as well that I have mentioned in the answer. I have asked you to change code in 2 places... make sure you have got it right...

Comment: But what if i don't want to get this alert box

Comment: @Jasmin remove alert and you can assign it to a variable... `$(this).attr('id')` will give you the id.. you can use it from there

Answer (score 0):

Parameters you are passing is not in order:

```
.delegate( "td", "click", function() {
```

You should first assign the click event and then the selector:

```
$( "#listbox" ).delegate(  "click", "td", function() {
     $( this ).toggleClass( "chosen" );
});
```

And you should also use [e.stopImmediatePropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) inside listbox click function.

Suggestion: You should use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on) method instead of delegate method.

Comment: Nope still not getting ID ...getting same as before --asd undefined--